# URL foi identificada como mal-intencionada e/ou abusiva API Facebook

Tags: facebook-sdk

Estou criando uma api de login por facebook e está em um servidor de testes criado recentemente. Menos de 2 semanas e ao preencher o domínio o facebook me retornou a mensagem:

> Essa URL foi identificada como mal-intencionada e/ou abusiva.

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como limpar isso ou algo... essa url nem existia a duas semanas e já está no mal intensionado.
Procurei em foruns, no facebook e até agora não encontrei nada a respeito.

Answer (score 0):

Pode-se abrir um pedido na área do Facebook developers, pois é o único meio para entender e tentar remover o domínio do radar de mal-intensionada deles.

Porém uma solução rápida é alterar a URL usada no aplicativo que está no radar dele. Se a url é `meusite.com.br` mudar para `brasil.meusite.com` por exemplo.